# Using frequency of column value in dataframe to calculate new column value

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

So I have an example dataframe that hold the columns id, count and username with id and count being numbers and username being a string.

For every row of the dataframe I want to set a value of a new column called 'ratio', with ratio being defined as

> count / number of rows where username == the username in this row

Example from the provided data:
In every row where the username is 'Tom' the ratio would be count/4 , because the user Tom is found four times in the data.

This is just a simplified version of my problem, a for-loop is not an option because my original dataframe has about 3.4 million rows and my previous approach where I used for-loops to iterate the unique values of e.g. 'username' to solve this problem takes forever.

dput of my dataframe:

```
structure(list(id = 1:20, count = c(140L, 89L, 17L, 114L, 129L, 
86L, 21L, 50L, 197L, 160L, 8L, 14L, 78L, 208L, 155L, 55L, 63L, 
20L, 189L, 79L), usernames = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Jerry", 
"Mark", "Phil", "Tina", "Tom"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"count", "usernames"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I hope I provided everything for you to understand and reproduce the problem, if something's missing don't hesitate to mention it in the comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several options. Here are three, one in base R, one with `data.table`, and one with "plyr". Both assume we're starting with a data.frame named "mydf":

#### Base R

```
within(mydf, {
  temp <- as.numeric(ave(as.character(usernames), usernames, FUN = length))
  ratio <- count/temp
  rm(temp)
})
```

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, ratio := count/.N, by = "usernames"]
DT
```

#### plyr

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, .(usernames), transform,
      ratio = count/length(usernames))
```

Comment: very nice solution. Sadly, I just realized that my example was oversimplified to a degree where it does not depict the actual problem. I'll vote to delete my question and post a new one. I'm sorry to have wasted your time on this one

Comment: @Rickyfox, I would say that protocol is to either (1) accept the answer and post a new question if the question is significantly different from the one asked, or (2) update the question with relevant details if the question is not significantly different and you think one of the answers might be modifiable to suit the new requirements. Stack Overflow is not just to get *your* specific question answered, but also a platform for others to derive answers from similar problems. Please keep that in mind before deleting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ave` for this:

```
transform(d, x=count/as.numeric(ave(d$usernames, d$usernames, FUN=length)))
```

Comment: +1 to you. I just realized that we have almost the same base R answer :)