# Get number of rows with same value in one column and positive binary value in another column

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

(Sorry for the weird title but I just couldn't think of a short way to put this)

Since I managed to oversimplify my problem in the last question I asked, I'm providing you with the actual problem this time.

The provided dataframe contains the columns "usr" , "usrMsgCnt" and "isRefound" with usr being a name, usrMsgCnt being a number and isRefound being binary.

A new column is to be added whichs value is calculated as follows:

> usrMsgCnt/ number of rows where usr is equal to the usr of this line
>   and isRefound is equal to 1

For the example data's first row the new value would be:

> 9 / 5 with 5 being produced by
>   length(data$usr[data$usr=="Jan.Schrader" & data$isRefound==1])

Looping through this is not an option considering the size of the original dataset

Here's the dput of a tiny chunk of the data

```
structure(list(usr = structure(c(21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 21L, 20L, 21L, 6L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 6L, 6L
), .Label = c("alsmith", "Amanda.Coles", "Andrew.Coles", "babsimieth", 
"Bernd.Ludwig", "Bernhard.Schiemann", "bfueck", "Bram.Ridder", 
"brian.tripney", "carlosgardeazabal", "christine.elsweiler", 
"cmfinner", "daniel.goncalves", "david", "de56", "eko.ma", "freundlu", 
"gmcphail", "ian.ferguson", "Ian.Ruthven", "Jan.Schrader", "jearmour", 
"jyang", "Laura.Schnall", "Marc.Roper", "marek.maleika", "Martin.Hacker", 
"martin.scholz", "maziminke", "mclanger", "Michael.Cashmore", 
"morgan.harvey", "mrussell", "msherrif", "murray.wood", "Nadine.Mahrholz", 
"noam.ascher", "pburns", "Peter.Gregory", "raina", "robertnm", 
"ronald.teijeira", "ronaldtf", "sbenus", "starmstr", "steve.neely", 
"Sven.Friedemann", "tinchen"), class = "factor"), usrMsgCnt = c(9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 9L, 5L, 0L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
37L, 37L, 37L), isRefound = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("usr", 
"usrMsgCnt", "isRefound"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perhaps to eliminate any ambiguity, you can post what you expect to be the output of the subset of the data you've shared here.

Comment: yeah you're right, give me a minute

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `isRefound` is actually binary:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF,key="usr")

DT[,newvar:=usrMsgCnt/sum(isRefound),by=usr]
```

**Edit:** If the order is essential, you should not set the key (which orders the data.table) and create an index variable (for safety).

```
DT <- data.table(DF)
DT[,id:=.I]
DT[,newvar:=usrMsgCnt/sum(isRefound),by=usr]
print(DT)

#                    usr usrMsgCnt isRefound id newvar
#  1:       Jan.Schrader         9         0  1    1.8
#  2:       Jan.Schrader         9         1  2    1.8
#  3:       Jan.Schrader         9         1  3    1.8
#  4:       Jan.Schrader         9         1  4    1.8
#  5: Bernhard.Schiemann         5         1  5    1.0
#  6:       Bernd.Ludwig         0         0  6    NaN
#  7: Bernhard.Schiemann         5         0  7    1.0
#  8: Bernhard.Schiemann         5         1  8    1.0
#  9: Bernhard.Schiemann         5         1  9    1.0
# 10:       Jan.Schrader         9         1 10    1.8
# 11:        Ian.Ruthven         0         0 11    NaN
# 12:       Jan.Schrader         9         0 12    1.8
# 13: Bernhard.Schiemann         5         1 13    1.0
# 14:        Ian.Ruthven         0         0 14    NaN
# 15:       Jan.Schrader         9         0 15    1.8
# 16:       Jan.Schrader         9         0 16    1.8
# 17:       Jan.Schrader         9         1 17    1.8
# 18: Bernhard.Schiemann        37         0 18    7.4
# 19: Bernhard.Schiemann        37         1 19    7.4
# 20: Bernhard.Schiemann        37         0 20    7.4
```

---

The same conceptual approach can be used with the base R approach and plyr approach demonstrated [at your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555598/1270695):

```
within(DF, {
  newvar <- usrMsgCnt/ave(isRefound, usr, FUN = sum)
})

library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(usr), transform,
      newvar = usrMsgCnt/sum(isRefound))
```

However, performance of the data.table package will be superior for huge datasets.

Comment: +1. I was thinking along the same lines. Only change I would make is not adding the key in the data.table creation to keep the original row order, if it's required.

Comment: the original row order is essential, but I don't really understand what you mean by 'not adding the key in the data.table creation'  - care to elaborate?